# The use of the [upcoming-games] tag

Tags: discussion, upcoming-games

> Related Question:
>
> [Asking about upcoming game releases](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231/asking-about-upcoming-game-releases)

Checking the questions tagged with the [[upcoming-games]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upcoming-games) tag, they all seem highly speculative, argumentive or too localized.

What do we want with this tag, and do we even want this tag in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, this is one of the few tags, that actually can get blocked on the site, as any question asking about upcoming games, will always be hightly speculative, argumetative, or way too localized.

Comment: Any question that would *need* the tag [upcoming-games] would be too localized, and I agree. Any possibly valid question is probably going to be about a specific game, in which tagging the game is much more appropriate than [upcoming-games]. I agree with destroying the tag.

Comment: @grace -1, [example](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8585/medal-of-honor-open-beta-accounts-carry-over) [example](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8517/what-announcements-have-been-made-in-reference-to-the-beta-release-date-of-minecr) -- never mind the sole idea of being able to tell if a question deserves closing just by looking at its tags is pretty horrible.

Comment: @badp For both of those questions, I see a much better tag in the form of the game's name. So I don't see why the [upcoming-games] tag is necessary? Not to mention, you removed it from one of them yourself!

Comment: @Grace I removed it to see how many close votes would land on the question _afterwards_ through, you know, actually reading the question. That doesn't mean `upcoming-games` wouldn't apply as a tag.

Comment: @badp This isn't about "judging a question on its tags and disregarding the body", which I don't condone and I have neither stated nor suggested as a proper course of action. [upcoming-games] is a tag that either loses applicability or categorizes a kind of question that would be too localized. Rather than use a tag which needs to be removed after a period of time, the wiser choice is to simply use one of the many more useful tags. Game name, what holiday/event they're being released, company; pretty much any other tag in existence is a better tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree that speculation about upcoming games is really bad.

But I think it could be useful during private beta's, where players who made it in can answer questions that will help users prepare for the upcoming launch (as with WoW Cataclysm).

Also regarding Rock Band 3, I will have to make a choice between the different types of guitars, so I want to know which to choose BEFORE the launch, so I could get it on launch day.

So while I agree speculation is bad, I do see a use case for it. However, the questions as linked in [upcoming-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upcoming-games) mostly suck as a question anyway...

Comment: However, usually, private beta's are NDA burdened, so they can't use this site for their questions.

Comment: Private betas are. But many games have public betas as a marketing tool -  especially MMOs.